# Many message in logcat - Firebase and other

Tags: android, logging

When I debug my app, I see many log from Firebase, like these:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
```

but I do not use any Firebase method. In my api manager developer console I've enabled the following service:
Mobile Crash and Performance Reporting API

```
 App Engine Admin API
 BigQuery API
 Firebase Rules API
 Google Cloud APIs
 Google Cloud Datastore API
 Google Cloud Messaging
 Google Cloud SQL
 Google Cloud Storage
 Google Cloud Storage JSON API
 Google Places API Web Service
 Google+ API
 Identity Toolkit API
 Stackdriver Debugger API
 Stackdriver Logging API
 Stackdriver Monitoring API
 Stackdriver Trace API
 Token Service API
```

And these are my dependencies in build.gradle (app):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.davemorrissey.labs:subsampling-scale-image-view:3.4.1' //zoom image view
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar' //crop image
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0"
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0' //fab
    compile ('com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT'){exclude group: 'com.nineoldandroids'} //search bar
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.pkmmte.view:circularimageview:1.1' //circle image view
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

This problem is related to Firebase, I think, but there are another problem. I've an app to change wallpaper. It works with Nougat on Nexus 5 or with Marshmallow on emulator.
I've the following error when I closed it but there is a broadcast with alarm manager in background to change wallpaper:

```
Thread[2,tid=7185,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xaee57000,peer=0x12c560a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
```

then, a message tell me to see traces.txt in anr: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8qwgteGjSYIV19iQXZUU2U0S1k/view?usp=sharing

I think that the Firebase's logs doesn't create problem, but I would to resolve the "WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop".

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'` don't do this. Only compile the specific libraries you are using

Comment: Thanks, this solve many problems.